# Digital Image Processing

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to extract only urban aeas from satellite imagery Using Matlab. I have applied some edge detectors like canny and also used morphological functions and I am able to extract all the boundaries ,but not able to seperate them from various urban aeas like roads, trees and waterbodies.

Please help i can share the code if any one wants

Comment: To detect coloured areas (like summer forest, field, lake) you can convert image to HSV or HSL and detect 4-connected components having the same colour ($H = H_0 \pm \Delta H$). To detect buildings and direct roads you can for example apply Hough transform to your image with edges: two long parallels could be road and conglomeration of short lines could be an uptown.

Comment: This is not a simple Q&A question. This is a research problem. I'm very tempted to close this question of too broad. Please revise it to ask for specific image processing aspects you're having troubles with. I'm sure there are great academic papers out there to help you with the general topic.

Answer (score -2):

I think this code would be helpful, as displaying intensity part gives you the spatial characteristics of an image.

```
%Write a MATLAB function which converts an RGB to HSI. Display the Hue
%image, Saturation image and the Intensity image. Histogram equalize the H,
%S and I images and the HSI image. Then convert the HSI image back to RGB.

function rgbtohsi(x)
F=imread('C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\TM\tanya\img3.tif ');
F=im2double(F);
r=F(:,:,1);
g=F(:,:,2);
b=F(:,:,3);
th=acos((0.5*((r-g)+(r-b)))./((sqrt((r-g).^2+(r-b).*(g-b)))+eps));
H=th;
H(b>g)=2*pi-H(b>g);
H=H/(2*pi);
S=1-3.*(min(min(r,g),b))./(r+g+b+eps);
I=(r+g+b)/3;
hsi=cat(3,H,S,I);
HE=H*2*pi;
HE=histeq(HE);
HE=HE/(2*pi);
SE=histeq(S);
IE=histeq(I);
choice=input('1:RGB to HSI\n2:Display Hue, Saturation and Intensity Images\n3:HSI to         
    RGB\n4:Hue-Equalization\n5:Saturation-Equalization\n6:Intensity-
    Equalization\n7:HSI-   Equalization\n Enter your choice :');
switch choice
case 1
    figure,imshow(F),title('RGB Image');
    figure, imshow(hsi),title('HSI Image');
case 2
    figure,imshow(F),title('RGB Image');
    figure, imshow(H),title('Hue Image');
    figure, imshow(S),title('Saturation Image');
    figure, imshow(I),title('Intensity Image');   
case 3
    C=hsitorgb(hsi);
    figure,imshow(hsi),title('HSI Image');
    figure, imshow(C),title('RGB Image');
case 4
    RV=cat(3,HE,S,I);
    C=hsitorgb(RV);
    figure,imshow(hsi),title('HSI Image');
    figure,imshow(F),title('RGB Image');
    figure, imshow(C),title('RGB Image-Hue Equalized');
case 5
    RV=cat(3,H,SE,I);
    C=hsitorgb(RV);
    figure,imshow(hsi),title('HSI Image');
    figure,imshow(F),title('RGB Image');
    figure, imshow(C),title('RGB Image-Saturation Equalized');
case 6
    RV=cat(3,H,S,IE);
    C=hsitorgb(RV);
    figure,imshow(hsi),title('HSI Image');
    figure,imshow(F),title('RGB Image');
    figure, imshow(C),title('RGB Image-Intensity Equalized');
case 7
    RV=cat(3,HE,SE,IE);
    C=hsitorgb(RV);
    figure,imshow(hsi),title('HSI Image');
    figure,imshow(F),title('RGB Image');
    figure, imshow(C),title('RGB Image-HSI Equalized');
    F1=C;
    otherwise
    display('Wrong choice');
end
end
    function C=hsitorgb(hsi)
    HV=hsi(:,:,1)*2*pi;
    SV=hsi(:,:,2);
    IV=hsi(:,:,3);
    R=zeros(size(HV));
    G=zeros(size(HV));
    B=zeros(size(HV));
%RG Sector
    id=find((0<=HV)& (HV<2*pi/3));
    B(id)=IV(id).*(1-SV(id));
    R(id)=IV(id).*(1+SV(id).*cos(HV(id))./cos(pi/3-HV(id)));
    G(id)=3*IV(id)-(R(id)+B(id));

%BG Sector
    id=find((2*pi/3<=HV)& (HV<4*pi/3));
    R(id)=IV(id).*(1-SV(id));
    G(id)=IV(id).*(1+SV(id).*cos(HV(id)-2*pi/3)./cos(pi-HV(id)));
    B(id)=3*IV(id)-(R(id)+G(id));
%BR Sector
    id=find((4*pi/3<=HV)& (HV<2*pi));
    G(id)=IV(id).*(1-SV(id));
    B(id)=IV(id).*(1+SV(id).*cos(HV(id)-4*pi/3)./cos(5*pi/3-HV(id)));
    R(id)=3*IV(id)-(G(id)+B(id));
    C=cat(3,R,G,B);
    C=max(min(C,1),0);
end
```